# Django Rest Framework - HyperlinkedRelatedField for abstract base class

Tags: django-rest-framework

My question is if is possible to add an HyperlinkedRelatedField in a serializer to get only the attributes of the base class. for example:

I want a json like that:

```
{
  "modules": [
    {
      "moduleName": "M1: Fundamentos Técnicos",
      "moduleDetails": "Bla bla bla.",
      "moduleID": 0,
      "userScore": 3,
      "slides": [
        {
          "slideType": "Content",
          "slideID": 0
        },
        {
          "slideType": "Minigame1",
          "slideID": 1
        },
        {
          "slideType": "Video",
          "slideID": 6
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here, Slide is the base class and Video and Minigame are subclasses.
Is possible this?, is possible add a HyperlinkedRelatedField for the url of each slide?.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE!**

this are my models:

```
   class Module(TimeStampedModel):

       moduleID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
       moduleName = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='Nombre del modulo')
       moduleDetails = models.TextField(verbose_name='Detalle')
       moduleBullet1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Punto 1')
       moduleBullet2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Punto 2')
       moduleBullet3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Punto 3')
       moduleImageURL = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="modulos", verbose_name='Imagen')
       userScore = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default=0, verbose_name='Score de usuario')


    class Slide(TimeStampedModel):

        CONTENT = 'Content'
        MINIGAME = 'Minigame'
        VIDEO = 'Video'
        SLIDE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
            (CONTENT, 'Contenido'),
            (MINIGAME, 'Minigame'),
            (VIDEO, 'Video'),
        )
        slideType = models.CharField(
            max_length=20,
            choices=SLIDE_TYPE_CHOICES,
            default=CONTENT,
        )
        slideID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        slideOrder = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
            verbose_name='Orden de visualizacion')
        module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
            related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related",
            related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)ss",)

        class Meta:
            abstract = True

    class VideoContent(Slide):

        videoURL = models.URLField(verbose_name='URL de video')


    class Minigame(Slide):

        timeToFail=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

And in my serializers.py i want something like this:

```
class SlideSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Slide
        fields = ('url', 'slideType', 'slideID')

class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     slides = SlideSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
     class Meta:
         model = Module
         fields = ('moduleID', 'moduleName', 'moduleDetails', 'moduleImageURL', 'userScore', 'slides')
```

My view.py

```
class ModuleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """

    queryset = Module.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModuleSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

class SlideViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """

    queryset = Slide.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SlideSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```

Slide.Objects raise an error, AttributeError: type object 'Slide' has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: Can you add your models?  Also, your question is a little confusing to me: it sounds like you want to be using nested serializers and not HyperlinkedRelatedFields; can you try to clarify a bit more?

Comment: @Gerik i made an update

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having with this?  If I'm reading your code properly you've got the correct nested serializers.  The only difference is that it looks like it would include more fields than what you're asking for.  Again, a hyperlinked field generates what it says: a link field which I don't see in your response: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield.

Comment: Thanks @Gerik, my problem is that I don`t know how to continue implementing in the view

Comment: Gotcha: do you have a view in place already?

Comment: Question detail updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't query abstract base classes. Slice is an abstract class, you cannot use `queryset = Slide.objects.all()` in `SlideViewSet` because an abstract model isn't an actual database object, and therefore cannot be queried.

You have to choose between abstract inheritance, in which case there is no database relationship between the two classes, or multi-table inheritance, which keeps the database relationship at a cost of efficiency (an extra database join) for each query.

### Using multi-table inheritance

```
class Slide(TimeStampedModel):

    CONTENT = 'Content'
    MINIGAME = 'Minigame'
    VIDEO = 'Video'
    SLIDE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (CONTENT, 'Contenido'),
        (MINIGAME, 'Minigame'),
        (VIDEO, 'Video'),
    )
    slideType = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=SLIDE_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default=CONTENT,
    )
    slideID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slideOrder = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        verbose_name='Orden de visualizacion')
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related",
        related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)ss",)

class VideoContent(Slide):

    videoURL = models.URLField(verbose_name='URL de video')


class Minigame(Slide):

    timeToFail=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

Now, your viewset:

```
class SlideViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""
This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
`update` and `destroy` actions.
"""
queryset = Slide.objects.all()
serializer_class = SlideSerializer
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```

[Documentation on multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#meta-and-multi-table-inheritance):

> multi-table inheritance uses an implicit OneToOneField to link the
>   child and the parent, it’s possible to move from the parent down to
>   the child

Hope this clears the things up.

Comment: thanks mrehan! i think I'm going to the multi-table inheritance!